# Cognos Report Studio List Prompt HTML Item

Tags: html, list, prompt, cognos

I am working on a dashboard in Report Studio with list prompts that will load different reports.  I have a single list prompt and an HTML button that will launch the report selected from the list.  I am trying to add additional list prompts for different report categories.  The issue is that all of the HTML buttons will only look at one of the list prompts.  The excerpt from the script is as follows.  I change the .getControlByName() to reference my different list names, but that doesn't help.

```
<script>
function open_win()
var oCR = cognos.Report.getReport(); 
var myPrompt = oCR.prompt.getControlByName("classlist");
var v = myPrompt.getValues();
var selectedValue =v[0]['use'];
window.open(selectedValue);
return true;
```

I am not familiar with java script, so I am guessing at what these commands do.

Answer (score 0):

Each prompt needs its own Name property populated. Assuming you've done this is what the code would look like:

```
function open_win(section) {
     var oCR = cognos.Report.getReport(); 
     var value = oCR.prompt.getControlByName(section).getValues()[0].use;
     window.open(value);
}
```

For this to work, you'd have one HTML button for each section.

In each HTML button's onClick definition, call the universal open_win() function, passing in the name of the associated section which needs to match the associated prompt: e.g. open_win('classlist').